Dropdown of sources in Looker Studio
I'm creating a sales report in Looker Studio that combines data from multiple sources (various stores) into a single report. Currently, I'm blending all the sources together, but I'm looking for a way to add a dropdown menu that allows me to select which sources to include or exclude from the report.
I looked into using parameters, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.
